# how to compile C++ and CUDA files together using cmake in Windows platform

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, cuda

I want to compile .cpp file and .cu file together using cmake in Windows platform, I'm using CMakelists to set the compilation rule:

**CMakeLists:**

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)

set(CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR "C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v12.3")
set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER "C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\bin\\nvcc.exe")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe")

project(OCT_CUDA LANGUAGES CXX CUDA C)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 17)

if(MSVC)
    set(_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1)
    set(CURL_STATICLIB 1)
    set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER "C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v12.3\\bin\\nvcc.exe")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe")
    set (CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS "C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v12.3\\include")
    # set (CUDA_LIBRARIES "C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v12.3\\lib\\x64")
endif()

file(GLOB CU_FILES src/*.cu)
file(GLOB CPP_FILES "*.cpp")
file(GLOB CUH_FILES "*.cuh")

enable_language(CUDA)
find_package(CUDAToolkit REQUIRED)
include_directories("C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v12.3\\include")

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

link_directories("C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA \\GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v12.3\\lib\\x64")
link_directories("C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v12.3\\nvvm\\lib\\x64")

add_library(cuda_lib STATIC src/test.cu)
set_target_properties(cuda_lib PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
set_target_properties(cuda_lib PROPERTIES CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 86)
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}  ${CPP_FILES})

target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cuda_lib CUDA::cudart ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} )

target_compile_options(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>: -Xcudafe --diag_suppress_esa_on_defaulted_function_ignored --expt-relaxed-constexpr >
    PRIVATE $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>: >
)

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    target_compile_options(add PRIVATE $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:-G)
endif()
```

However, I always get the error:

```
LNK2019: External symbols that cannot be parsed
```

and error:

```
LNK1120: external command cannot be parsed.
```

It maybe means that .CU file was compiled by nvcc.exe and .cpp file was compiled by cl.exe. But when linkng these two parts together, CPP Compiler cl.exe cannot understand the function defined in .cu and .cuh files.

I have tried to just compile .cu file without .cuh and .cpp files, I found that it can run successfully. But when I compile .cu, .cuh and .cpp files together, the linker error occurred. Then I tried to add potential needed path into system environment variable path or user environment variable path. But it didn't work.
Then I tried to add `extern "C"` before the function defined in .cuh and .cu file, just like:

```
 extern "C" void h_vec_add(int *a, int *b, int *c, int n)
```

However, it also didn't work.
I wonder why I CAN'T compile cuda file and cpp file together in windows platform.

Comment: When you [edit] your post, learn the editor buttons and use an appropriate one for your code.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm new to here. Thank you for editing my problem again. Now it looks good.

Comment: I think that maybe I should compile CUDA file into dll library using visual studio in advance, then invoke the dll library in VScode